# How can it be, that routing doesn't work?

Tags: freebsd, routing, pfsense

I have connected with openvpn client to remote host and am able to ping it. Also route of this IP belongs correctly:

```
> ping 10.10.0.251
PING 10.10.0.251 (10.10.0.251): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.0.251: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=388.371 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.251: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=195.209 ms
^C
--- 10.10.0.251 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 195.209/291.790/388.371/96.581 ms
> route get 10.10.0.251
   route to: 10.10.0.251
destination: 10.10.0.0
       mask: 255.255.255.0
    gateway: 10.11.0.1
        fib: 0
  interface: ovpnc5
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    mtu        weight    expire
       0         0         0         0      1500         1         0
```

simultaneously, if I tracert this IP from Windows machine in LAN, it goes via different gateway

```
>tracert 10.10.0.251

Tracing route to 10.10.0.251 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.10.1
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  ISP router 1
  3     *        1 ms     1 ms  ISP router 2
```

where `192.168.10.1` is an `IP` of my router running `pfSense`.

How can it be theoretically? Who else can control packets route besides route table?

Comment: My guess is that your Linux host is routing through the OpenVPN connection and your Windows host isn't, but there's insufficient information to answer the question from what you have provided. What are your addresses and full routing tables (`ip addr`/`ifconfig` and `ip route`/`route` for Linux, `ipconfig` and `route print` for Windows)? How is the network set up?

Comment: @ErikF I don't have Linux host, I hav FreeBSD host which is the router `192.168.10.1`. Why `route get` result above is not enough? `route print 10.10.0.251` on Windows says `No active routes`. Tracert shows it goes to router, why doesn't it route it to VPN?

Comment: `route get` only shows that one route: in order to give a more complete answer, we need to know *all* the routes that the host can take. OpenVPN usually takes over as the default gateway, but without seeing all the routes, it's hard to know the whole picture.